# is there a way to access gps location of device through the cloud?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, cloud

I am trying to send push notifications out to users through the parse cloud and was wondering if there is a way with the device token to access their current location?  I have tried to see what information I can access through apples push notification server but it only tells me what information I can send not what I can receive.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't track the location of your users without their consent, and in most circumstances that will require your app to be running and sending location data to your service (e.g. saving it in Parse).

Anything else would be a gross violation of Privacy Rules, not gonna happen.

As mentioned by Fosco, the correct way to do it is to request location information through the usual API (which gets user permission), then save it in the Installation object.

Comment: But, if you get permission, and store last known location on the Installation object, it's trivially easy to send push notifications to those records within a sphere, or within a distance of a given point.

Comment: I figured that would be the case but thought I would ask just in case there was some other way. Thanks.